# Regex - match a specific word from specific email domains

Tags: regex, email

I would like to match a word from a string in the front part of an email address from a specific domains.

The word will be "main" and the domains are "gmail.com" and "hotmail.com"

example:

123main456@gmail.com  = match

123main@hotmail.com = match

someone@gmail.com = no match

The best that I can come out with is as below, but it does pass the validation...

```
(\W|^)[((?i)naim(?-i))]{0,25}@(yahoo|hotmail|gmail)\.com(\W|$)
```

Thank you.

Comment: This seems to work for me: `^.*main.*@(gmail|hotmail).com`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want the word `main` matched. I've used a lookahead where I've captured the word inside parentheses, only if it belongs to a `gmail` or `hotmail` domain.

Regex: `(?=(main).*@(?:gmail|hotmail).com)`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pH2aW2/2)

If you want one without a lookahead;

Regex: `(main).*@(?:gmail|hotmail).com`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pH2aW2/3)

In both cases `main` is captured in the parentheses.